# PHP Get hour difference in datetime

Tags: php, date, datetime, unix-timestamp

so I have these two time stamps in PHP

```
1253339331
1253338959
```

I want to be able to somehow get the hour difference between those to datetimes. Our users should only have 24 hours to login after their first attempt, so I need to find out if it's less than 24 hours to allow them to login again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if ((t2-t1)/3600) < 24 { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
( 1253339331 - 1253338959 ) / ( 60 * 60 )
```

This will give you number of hours between the two timestamps.

Comment: That's the number of minutes.

Comment: No, 60*60 is the number of seconds in an **hour**

Answer (score 3):

Those times are just seconds since Jan 1 1970 (see [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)); you can just subtract the two, then divide by (60 sec/min * 60 min/hr) to convert the seconds to hours.

So in your case, the times were only (1253339331-1253338959)/3600 = 0.1 hours apart.